# converting columns to rows using reset_index function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to unstack the columns of a pandas data frame that got created via a join on id columns

The df looks as below, The columns names of both the left table and right table are similar ( Not sure if I should rename them simply and it would solve the issue

```
id  county cat brand month country cat brand month
1    GB    x1   xx    12    GB      x2  x1    08
2    GB    x2   xx1   12    GB      x2  x1    09
```

I want to convert the above output to be stacked one below the other for the same id

for eg for id = 1

```
id  county cat brand month 
1    GB    x1   xx    12   
1    GB    x2   x1    08
```

Any easier way of doing this, I tried the below, however, it doesn't work

1. Create a new column call row_index_number

   df['row_number']=df.reset_index().index
2. Did an append and sorted by row number

   new = df[['id','county','cat','brand','month','row_number']]

   old = df[['id','county','cat','brand','month','row_number']]

   full = new.append(old)

   full = full.sort_values(by = ['row_number'])

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count duplicated column names and create `MultiIndex` by assign nested lists:

```
df = df.set_index('id') 

s = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = [s.groupby(s).cumcount(), s]
print (df)
         0                       1                
   country cat brand month country cat brand month
id                                                
1       GB  x1    xx    12      GB  x2    x1     8
2       GB  x2   xx1    12      GB  x2    x1     9

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], ['brand', 'cat', 'country', 'month']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3]])
```

And then call [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.stack(0)
print (df1)
     brand cat country  month
id                           
1  0    xx  x1      GB     12
   1    x1  x2      GB      8
2  0   xx1  x2      GB     12
   1    x1  x2      GB      9
```

And then select by `loc`:

```
print (df1.loc[1])
  brand cat country  month
0    xx  x1      GB     12
1    x1  x2      GB      8

print (df1.loc[2])
  brand cat country  month
0   xx1  x2      GB     12
1    x1  x2      GB      9
```

Answer (score 0):

In step 2 of transformation , renaming the columns before the join happens solves the issue

Did an append and sorted by row number

```
new = df[['id','county','cat','brand','month','row_number']]

old = df[['id','county_new','cat_new','brand_new','month_new','row_number']]

full = new.append(old)

full = full.sort_values(by = ['row_number'])
```